# jQuery Dropdown keeps closing when hovering from div to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I've made a dropdown from two different divs. One is the trigger and one the submenu.
If the mouse hovers from the trigger to the submenu, the submenu closes. How can I keep it open even when the mouse switches between the two divs?

Also I can't move the submenu-container inside the dropdown-trigger. They need to be two separate divs.

```
$('.dropdown-trigger,.submenu-container').hover(
  function(){$('.submenu-container').css('display', 'block')},
  function(){$('.submenu-container').css('display', 'none')},
);
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: have you tried to remove line "function(){$('.submenu-container').css('display', 'none')}"?

Comment: Yeah, that keeps it just open. But i need to hide it when the mouse leaves the trigger and the submenu

Comment: you might want to use this ugly solution then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557492/how-can-i-trigger-a-mouseout-event-for-two-elements-in-jquery but keep in mind that using timers like thi is generally considered a bad practiced

Comment: Thank you for the link! I've made it work in the Demo! :-D Now i need to translate it into my programming xD @Kajbo

Comment: Try this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0u13v7my)

Answer (score 0):

You may not need jquery. you can do by css. Similar way u can do in jquery

```css
.dropdown {
  max-width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.item.default {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.dropdown:hover .item {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .item.default {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="item default">Select <span>V</span></li>
      <li class="item">1</li>
      <li class="item">1</li>
      <li class="item">1</li>
      <li class="item">1</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: but the problem is, that the two divs (trigger and submenu) are not near each other or parents...

Comment: than it is tough! can u provide sandbox example?